# Search function doesn't work when deleting the searchTerm in the searchbar

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a search functionality that filters users in a list. It works super fine when searching a user for a first time. Like for example searchTerm ="User1" => I get User 1. But if I change my term to ="Us" e.g. I still only have User1 and the other users aren't shown anymore. So the problem is like reverse filtering. From "" to "user" works. but from "user" to "" doesn't. How can I fix that? When I log the `console.log(result);` It exactly shows the problem. The array is filtered but when deleting things the array just stays filtered.

My Code:
userservice.ts

```
getList(): Observable<any> {
return this.http.get(this.url)
  }
```

page.ts

```
   public searchTerm: string = "";
        userList: Observable<any>;
        offset = 0;
        searching = false;

       ngOnInit() {
        this.getAllUsers();
        }


     getAllUsers() {
        this.userList = this.userService.getList()
            .pipe(map(response => response.results));
          }

        filterUsers(searchTerm) {
        this.searching = true;
        return this.userList.pipe(
        map(res => {
        const result = res.filter(user => {
        return user.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                });
        this.searching = false;
        console.log(result);
        return result;
              })
            );
          }

        searchList() {
        this.userList = this.filterUsers(this.searchTerm);
        console.log(this.searchTerm);
          }
```

page.html

```
<ion-searchbar mode="ios" class="items-searchbar" animated mode="ios" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ionChange)="searchList()" placeholder="Filter by name..."></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list class="pad" mode="ios">
<ion-item lines="none" *ngFor="let user of (userList | async); let i = index">
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you are using "getAllUsers()" only on init. And when you filter your list you are setting your userlist to the filtered list. I guess you need to use "getAllUsers()" before every filtering or save all users in a separate list which you can filter afterwards.

Comment: filterUsers(searchTerm) {
        this.searching = true;
        this.getAllUsers();
        return this.userList.pipe(
        map(res => {
        const result = res.filter(user => {
        return user.username.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                });
        this.searching = false;
        console.log(result);
        return result;
              })
            );
          }